# Calculating means with stat_summary for two different groupings and plotting in one plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having issues with plotting two calculated means using stat_summary in the same figure.

I am using ggplot and stat_summary to plot means of a dataset that I grouped based on variable A. Variable A can have value 1,2,3,4. The same data also have variable B that can have value 1,2.
So, I can make a plot with means of the data grouped after variable A, and I get 4 lines.
I can also make a plot with means of the data grouped after variable B, where I get 2 lines.
But how can I plot them in the same figure, so that I get 6 lines? I have made a somewhat similar example using the mtcars dataset:

```
library(ggplot2)
mtcars$cyl <- as.factor(mtcars$cyl)
mtcars$vs <- as.factor(mtcars$vs)
mtcars

plot1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=gear, y=hp, color=cyl, fill=cyl)) +
  stat_summary(geom='ribbon', fun.data = mean_cl_normal, fun.args=list(conf.int=0.95), alpha=0.5) +
  stat_summary(geom='line', fun.y = mean, size=1)
plot1
```

[image]

```
plot2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=gear, y=hp, color=vs, fill=vs)) +
  stat_summary(geom='ribbon', fun.data = mean_cl_normal, fun.args=list(conf.int=0.95), alpha=0.5) +
  stat_summary(geom='line', fun.y = mean, size=1)
plot2
```

[image]

So far I have the impression, that since I start with ggplot(xxx), where xxx defines the data and grouping, I can't combine it with another ggplot with another grouping. If I could initiate ggplot() without defining anything in the argument, but only defining data and grouping in the argument for stat_summary, I feel like that would be the solution. But I can't figure out how to use stat_summary like that, if even possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add more layers, defining the `aes` for each seperately:

```
ggplot(mtcars) +
  stat_summary(aes(x=gear, y=hp, color=paste('cyl:', cyl), fill = paste('cyl:', cyl)), geom='ribbon', fun.data = mean_cl_normal, fun.args=list(conf.int=0.95), alpha=0.5) +
  stat_summary(aes(x=gear, y=hp, color=paste('cyl:', cyl)), geom='line', fun.y = mean, size=1) +
  stat_summary(aes(x=gear, y=hp, color=paste('vs:', vs), fill=paste('vs:', vs)), geom='ribbon', fun.data = mean_cl_normal, fun.args=list(conf.int=0.95), alpha=0.5) +
  stat_summary(aes(x=gear, y=hp, color=paste('vs:', vs)), geom='line', fun.y = mean, size=1)
```

Comment: That's great, thanks! It adds some text to the legend I can't seem to remove: https://imgur.com/a/5NhKQLV. Can you help with that?

Comment: That's what I'm doing with `paste('cyl:', cyl)` and `paste('vs:', vs)`, just to make sure that they have unique levels and that you can see which variable you are referring to.